# VS cant browse SSAS cube

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, olap-cube, sql-server-2012-datatools

When I try to browse a cube in VS2012 it will crash my VS instance even though it deployed perfectly fine.  I have tried different combinations of uninstalling and re-installing software.  I am wondering what could possibly be missing.

I have analysis services running as a service

I have SQL server Data tools installed

I have Office Dev Tools for VS2012 installed

I have SQL Server Management studio installed

I have Office installed

I am able to browse the cube fine in excel

Comment: what error are you getting?  Maybe  check the event logs. Can you browse the cube in SSMS?

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception when i run it in the debugger, however, other machines run this exact cube fine. I am indeed able to browse the cube in SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team was unable to pinpoint the problem.  Reformatting the machine and installing everything fresh fixed the problem quickly.  No way to fully know what went wrong but there were some strange registry entries that may or may not have contributed to the problem even if the logs didn't show that.